# Acumatica - Field Verifying on OrderQty

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am trying to set a warning on the OrderQty field when a certain UOM is selected. We have a UOM that is only in qty multiples of 50 so this must mean that the qty should be set to a multiple of 50. I would like a warning to display if the user entered let's say 40 then it would say this should be entered in a multiple of 50. My code compiles fine it just does not throw the warning when entering a value that should throw the exception.

SOOrder Entry Graph:

```
protected void SOLine_OrderQty_FieldVerifying(PXCache cache, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
    {

      var row = (SOLine)e.Row;

      if (row == null) return;

      SOLine line = Base.Transactions.Current;

      if (line.UOM != "CCP") return;
      if (line.UOM == "CCP")
        {
          if (line.OrderQty % 50 == 0) return;
          else
            {
              throw new PXSetPropertyException("Please enter a value in multiples of 50.", PXErrorLevel.Warning);
            }
        }

    }
```

I have also tried:

```
protected void SOLine_OrderQty_FieldVerifying(PXCache cache, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
    {

      var row = (SOLine)e.Row;

      if (row == null) return;

      if (row.UOM != "CCP") return;
      if (row.UOM == "CCP")
        {
          if (row.OrderQty % 50 == 0) return;
          else
            {
              throw new PXSetPropertyException("Please enter a value in multiples of 50.", PXErrorLevel.Warning);
            }
        }

    }
```

CCP is the UOM that should only have Qty's in the multiples of 50 and no other UOM should throw a warning if it is not set.

**Update 1:**
Updated the code to this:

```
 protected void SOLine_OrderQty_FieldVerifying(PXCache cache, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
    {

      var row = (SOLine)e.Row;

      if (row == null) return;

      if (row.UOM != "CCP") return;
      if (row.UOM == "CCP")
        {

          if ((decimal?)e.NewValue % 50 == 0) return;
          if ((decimal?) e.NewValue % 50 != 0)
    {
        cache.RaiseExceptionHandling<SOLine.orderQty>(e.Row, ((SOLine)e.Row).OrderQty,
            new PXSetPropertyException("Please enter a value in multiples of 50.", PXErrorLevel.Warning));
    }
        }

    }
```

I have changed to the e.NewValue state for the value entered. The warning message is still not thrown.

Comment: No an answer, just to point out some little things in your sample code. Should `var row = (SOLine)e.Row;` be `var row = e.Row as  SOLine;`? And `if (line.UOM == "CCP")` is not needed.

Comment: Both will provide the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking at the PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs NewValue (`e.NewValue`) to see what the new entered value is.

Example: `(decimal?)e.NewValue % 50 == 0`

When you use the row OrderQty you are looking at the value before the user entered the new value. To get the new value the user entered you need to look at NewValue for any field verifying event.

The `SOOrderEntry` graph has an example of its use on OrderQty:

```
protected virtual void SOLine_OrderQty_FieldVerifying(PXCache sender, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
{
    if ((decimal?)e.NewValue < ((SOLine)e.Row).ClosedQty && ((SOLine)e.Row).RequireShipping == true && (((SOLine)e.Row).LineType == "GI" || ((SOLine)e.Row).LineType == "GN"))
    {
        throw new PXSetPropertyException(CS.Messages.Entry_GE, sender.GetStateExt<SOLine.closedQty>(e.Row));
    }
}
```

Because of the thrown exception the warning will display but also cancel the entered value entered by the user. Because you are asking for a warning I assume you want to allow the user to enter in a non 50 lot qty value (and keep the entered value).

This example will surface the warning without cancelling the user entered value:

```
protected void SOLine_OrderQty_FieldVerifying(PXCache cache, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e, PXFieldVerifying del)
{
    if ((decimal?) e.NewValue % 50 != 0)
    {
        cache.RaiseExceptionHandling<SOLine.orderQty>(e.Row, ((SOLine)e.Row).OrderQty,
            new PXSetPropertyException("Please enter a value in multiples of 50.", PXErrorLevel.Warning));
    }

    if (del != null)
    {
        del(cache, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example just for the integrity of the answer?

Comment: I changed my if statement parameters to the one stated above it still does not throw the warning, do I have to save to invoke?

Comment: On my instance using that code, as soon as i enter the value and tab off of the screen the warning is visible.

Comment: Got it, it was the RaiseExceptionHandling that was missing. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it throws the warning but not at first. I tab away and it doesn't throw but if I go back in to change it from 40 to 50 it will then revert back to 40 and throw the error.

Comment: Maybe you have another customization causing issues? When testing the latest 2018R1 - after i tab off the entered value the warning is always available when using the last example in my answer. Trace your code to make sure the value it is testing against is actually the value you are trying to test because it doesn't sound like its firing correctly.

Comment: I updated the code above and this is a pretty fresh instance. There's nothing that is modified regarding UOM or OrderQty. I'm using version 17.203.0029 if that means anything. Does it have to deal with the UOM not being cached yet?

Comment: Using 17.209 works the same as 2018R1. Add something to trace your info to confirm its getting the correct values. After you declare your row variable add this... PXTrace.WriteInformation("SOLine_OrderQty_FieldVerifying {0}:{1}:{2} NewValue = {3} {4}", row.OrderType, row.OrderNbr, row.LineNbr, e.NewValue, row.UOM); and after you change the value in the page look at the trace window. what do you get?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173907/discussion-between-dane-and-brendan).

Comment: This answer does work, I was having a cache issue that would not update code.

Comment: I'm expanding on this code in the discussion chat above if you would like to join in.  I'm making that 50 for the modulus number to be the UnitRate on the INUnit table to expand this to all conversion types.